# Отследить запускаемый процессом процесс

Tags: python, powershell

Я запускаю программу с помощью `subprocess.run()` с целью отследить общее время работы в этой программе. При это специфика работы программы такова, что она завершает свой процесс и открывает себя вновь другим процессом (названия процессов совпадают, PID не совпадают, проверил с помощью `(Get-Process ИМЯ_ПРОЦЕССА| Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId).ID`). Соответственно, subprocess.run() возвращает мне управление, хотя нужная программа продолжает работу.

Я мог бы захардкодить программу, потому что я знаю имя искомого процесса и я могу просто начать счет времени через секунду после запуска, но я хотел бы найти более универсальный способ.

Я видел, что кто-то получает дочерние процессы с помощью `Tasklist /fi 'IMAGENAME eq ИМЯ_ПРОЦЕССА' /v`, но процесс переоткрывается быстрее, чем эта команда срабатывает, поэтому я получаю информацию о новом процессе

Comment: [Пример программы](https://github.com/Symbiograph/linux-sensation/blob/master/exec-notify.c), которая  занимается мониторигом событий (в т.ч. fork, основана на интерфейсе [netlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html)) в Linux. Зная pid, процесса, запускаемого subprocess.run() вы можете его мониторить и получать pids его child-ов. (может быть поможет вам конкретизировать процесс поиска решения)

Comment: @avp может быть и поможет, спасибо. Поищу аналоги используемых функций под винду

Comment: А командлет [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.3) пробовали?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Теперь пробовал. Вызов Measure-Command { ./test.ps1 | Out-Default}, где в test.ps1 содержится вызов exe с помощью & без параметров. Проблема та же самая — время мгновенно возвращается, а приложение себя перезапускает и дальше работает

Comment: По хорошему следовало вызывать исполнимый файл с помощью необходимой опции ожидания: **Start-Process - Wait c:\Folder\my.exe**. Тогда скрипт дождался бы окончания исполнения и было бы получено полное  время выполнения с помощью  **Measure-Command**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал удовлетворительный способ сделать то, что я хотел.
Понадобится модуль **psutil**

```
now = time.time()
proc = psutil.Popen(ПУТЬ_К_ПРОГРАММЕ)
    name = proc.name()
    proc.wait()
    for proc2 in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc2.name() == name:
        proc2.wait()
now2 = time.time()
session_time = now2-now
```

Работает как и с "нормальными" приложениями, так и с теми, которые перезапускают себя через лаунчер